# What is the difference between Mathematica Rules and the objects returned by GraphEdit?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-expressions

This is actually a two-fold question. First: as someone coming from an OO programming background, I find Mathematica's use of lists as the basis of everything a bit annoying. So here is how a mathematica programmer (as far as I can tell) might define a graph:

```
graph={{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1->2, 2->4, 4->4, 4->5}};
```

and then the programmer would just have to remember that

```
graph[[1]]
```

refers to the list of vertices and

```
graph[[2]]
```

refers to the list of edges (in this case defined as a set of rules.)

So, I was learning about the rules in Mathematica and I saw an opportunity to make my data structures a little more object-oriented feeling. I chose to define a graph something like:

```
graph={Verts->{1,2,3,4,5}, Edges->{1->2, 2->4, 4->4, 4->5}};
```

and then refer to vertices and edges (respectively) by

```
Verts/.graph
Edges/.graph
```

This can have weird side effects, however, if some other Mathematica file has defined Verts or Edges as a global variable somewhere, however, since the left hand side of the rule is not an identifier, but is itself an object.

So question 1 is this: is this a good practice, or a bad one for creating Mathematica data structures? One of the reasons I'm doing it this way is so that I can attach arbitrary properties, say colors:

```
AppendTo[graph, Colors->{Red, Red, Blue, Red, Red}]; (* Labels ea. vert with a color *)
```

and my functions don't have to know the exact order particular properties were added. For instance you might have a function GetColor defined like:

```
GetColor[graph_, vertIdx_]:=(Colors/.graph)[[vertIdx]];
```

and this is preferable, because I might not always want to have graph data structures that have Color info and so don't want to reserve a spot in the list (like graph[[[3]]]) for color information.

Second: I see that GraphEdit returns something that looks like the rules I've described above. For instance, if I execute (and draw a graph)

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"];
g = GraphEdit[];
g[[2]]
```

I get output like:

```
Graph->{1->2,3->3,4->4,5->4}
```

which looks like a rule! So I try this:

```
Graph/.g[[2]]
```

expecting to have

```
{1->2,3->3,4->4,5->4}
```

returned. But instead the output is just

```
Graph
```

But if I instead execute

```
g[[2]][[1]] /. g[[2]]
```

I get the expected output,

```
{1->2,3->3,4->4,5->4}
```

which means that g[[2]] really is a rule, but for some reason g[[2]][[1]] (which if executed prints Graph) is not the same as typing Graph. So what the heck is g[[2]][[1]]?

It seems almost like it is a real identifier, which if so, I would like to use to solve the problems with question 1 above. Anyone know the difference, or how to type one vs. the other into Mathematica?

I cannot find anything in the documentation about any of this (or online). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GraphEdit Rules**

`GraphEdit` returns a list whose first element is a `Graphics` object and whose remaining elements are rules that describe the graph.  The left-hand side of each rule is a string, not a symbol.  You can determine this using `g // FullForm`.  To extract the graph rules, you must ignore the first element of the list, e.g.

```
"Graph" /. Drop[g, 1]
```

**Simulating Record Types**

It is a reasonable approach to implement record-like data types as you propose:

```
graph={Verts->{1,2,3,4,5}, Edges->{1->2, 2->4, 4->4, 4->5}};
```

It is true that if `Verts` and `Edges` were assigned values, then "weird side effects" would occur.  However, there are a couple of ways to mitigate that problem.

First, there is an extremely widespread convention within Mathematica to avoid assigning values (specifically `OwnValues`) to symbols with upper case initial letters.  Wolfram prefixes all top-level variables with `$`, e.g. `$Context`.  If you stick to these conventions, you get some measure of safety.

Second, there is provision for separate namespaces using [Packages](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SettingUpMathematicaPackages.html).  Within the bounds of a package you define, you can have complete control over the bindings of symbols that you use as field names.

Third, you can use [Protect](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Protect.html) to prevent field names from having values assigned to them.

When implementing these record types, one could follow a LISP idiom and define constructor and accessor functions.  For the graph example, these functions could look something like this:

```
ClearAll[makeGraph, graphVertices, graphEdges]
makeGraph[vertices_, edges_] := {Verts -> vertices, Edges -> edges}
graphVertices[graph_] := Verts /. graph
graphEdges[graph_] := Edges /. graph
```

These functions would be used thus:

```
graph = makeGraph[{1,2,3,4,5}, {1->2,2->4,4->4,4->5}]
(* {Verts -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, Edges -> {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 4, 4 -> 5}} *)

graphVertices[graph]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)

graphEdges[graph]
(* {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 4, 4 -> 5} *)
```

Using this scheme, the field keys `Verts` and `Edges` can be private to a package and protected, completely avoiding the prospect of an accidental value assignment ruining things.

In Mathematica, it is extremely common to use the `Head` of an expression to identify its type.  We can conform to this idiom and redefine our record functions thus:

```
ClearAll[makeGraph, graphVertices, graphEdges]
makeGraph[vertices_, edges_] := graphRecord[Verts -> vertices, Edges -> edges]
graphVertices[graphRecord[rules___]] := Verts /. {rules}
graphEdges[graphRecord[rules___]] := Edges /. {rules}
```

The only material difference between these and the preceding definitions is that the graph object is now represented by an expression of the form `graphRecord[...]` instead of `{...}`:

```
graph = makeGraph[{1,2,3,4,5}, {1->2,2->4,4->4,4->5}]
(* graphRecord[Verts -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, Edges -> {1->2, 2->4, 4->4, 4->5}] *)

graphVertices[graph]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)

graphEdges[graph]
(* {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 4, 4 -> 5} *)
```

Why the change?  The first reason is that the head `graphRecord` now positively identifies the type of data whereas before it was just a list.  Second, we can define further functions (quasi-methods) that will only act on `graphRecord`s and nothing else.  For example:

```
graphEdgeCount[r_graphRecord] := graphEdges[r] // Length
graphEdgeCount[x_] := (Message[graphEdgeCount::invArg, x]; Abort[])
graphEdgeCount::invArg = "Invalid argument to graphEdgeCount: ``";
```

Use:

```
graphEdgeCount[graph]
(* 4 *)

graphEdgeCount["hi"]
```

> During evaluation of graphEdgeCount::invArg: Invalid argument to graphEdgeCount: hi
> $Aborted

As a final elaboration to all of this, it would be possible to define a macro function that automatically defined all the record functions given the type and field names.  However, as this response is already TL;DR, that is probably best left as topic for another question some day.

Note: If these functions were all defined within the context of a package, their names would use initial capitals (e.g. `MakeGraph` instead of `makeGraph`).  Beware, however, that Mathematica already has lots of built-in symbols that include the word `Graph`.

Comment: Wow, this is very useful, and filled in a lot of the holes in my understanding of Mathematica. I think they should write a document for the Mathematica documentation called something like, Mathematica Programming for C/Java/C++ Programmers with its content being something like, here is what you might do in C/Java/C++, here is the appropriate way to do it in Mathematica... They might think of having you write it.

Comment: @quadelirus When it comes to filling holes in one's understanding of Mathematica, an excellent resource is Leonid Shifrin's [Mathematica programming: an advanced introduction](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/).

Answer (score 4):

I wonder what version of Mathematica you're using?

Graph theory is more tightly integrated into V8's core, and this is largely an improvement.  You can interact with graphs in a way that an object oriented programmer might like.  In V8, I'd perform your example like so:

```
g = Graph[Range[5], {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 4, 4 -> 5}];
g = SetProperty[{g, 3}, VertexStyle -> Red]
```

I can then query the property like so:

```
PropertyValue[{g, 3}, VertexStyle]
```

Unfortunately, most of the older graph theory functionality doesn't play nicely in V8.  Although, you can use it if you're careful with context specification.  In V7, I might access the output of `GraphEdit` like so:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"];
g = GraphEdit[];
```

And then,

```
{vertices, edges} = {"VertexLabels", "Graph"} /. Rest[g]
```

to get something worth passing to other functions, like `GraphPlot`.

This partly answers your question as to whether this is a reasonable representation.  This type of representation makes it easy to access the information via replacement rules.  A good example of this is given by the way XML import works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to question 2 using InputForm[] (hadn't known about that function before today.)

```
InputForm[g[[2]][[1]]];
```

returns

```
"Graph"
```

So, it appears the way to avoid the problems in question 1 and the answer to how they define the GraphEdit stuff is to use strings in rules as "identifiers."

Question 1, then can be revised to: is this a good practice?

Comment: You may also find `FullForm` interesting. For instance, try `FullForm[g]`. Most objects in mathematica are interesting to look at this way, e.g., try `Plot[Sin[x], {x, -5, 5}]` followed by `FullForm@%`. So one can usually do this sort of thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477649/replacing-disks-by-crosses-using-graphics-in-mathematica/6478079#6478079  (this is fairly general in mathematica: the "real" form of things is an expression and can be manipulated like other expressions)